# Help on subsetting data frames using multiple logical operators in R

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to write a function to subset and exclude observations in a data frame based on three variables. My data looks something like this:

```
data.frame':   43 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "ENSG00000008438" "ENSG00000048462" "ENSG00000006075" "ENSG00000049130" ...
     $ V2: chr  "ENST00000008938" "ENST00000053243" "ENST00000225245" "ENST00000228280" ...
 $ V3: chr  "ENSP00000008938" "ENSP00000053243" "ENSP00000225245" "ENSP00000228280" ...
     $ V4: chr  "PGLYRP1" "TNFRSF17" "CCL3" "KITLG" ...
 $ V5: chr  "19" "16" "17" "12" ...
     $ V6: chr  "q13.32" "p13.13" "q12" "q21.32" ...
 $ V7: int  46522415 12058964 34415602 88886566 8276226 150285143 29138654 76424442 136871919 6664568 ...
     $ V8: int  46526304 12061925 34417515 88974238 8291203 150294844 29190208 76448092 136875735 6670599 ...
>
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
input = function(x) {
        pruned1 <- subset(x[-which(x$V5 == 1 & x$V7 > 113818477 & x$V8 < 114658477), ])
        pruned2 <- subset(pruned1[-which(pruned1$V5 == 1 & pruned1$V7 > 192461456 & pruned1$V8 < 192549912), ])
        # and so on
        }
```

So I want to take my original data frame, exlude observations that fulfil all three of the subsetting conditions, make a new object of the remaining observations (pruned1) and exclude any observations that fulfil a new set of condidtions and so on.

The problem I am having seems to be the third condition in the first subsetting, as this returns:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ V1: chr NA
     $ V2: chr NA
 $ V3: chr NA
     $ V4: chr NA
 $ V5: chr NA
     $ V6: chr NA
 $ V7: int NA
     $ V8: int NA
```

While only using the first two conditions returns:

```
'data.frame':   38 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "ENSG00000008438" "ENSG00000048462" "ENSG00000006075" "ENSG00000049130" ...
     $ V2: chr  "ENST00000008938" "ENST00000053243" "ENST00000225245" "ENST00000228280" ...
 $ V3: chr  "ENSP00000008938" "ENSP00000053243" "ENSP00000225245" "ENSP00000228280" ...
     $ V4: chr  "PGLYRP1" "TNFRSF17" "CCL3" "KITLG" ...
 $ V5: chr  "19" "16" "17" "12" ...
     $ V6: chr  "q13.32" "p13.13" "q12" "q21.32" ...
 $ V7: int  46522415 12058964 34415602 88886566 8276226 150285143 29138654 76424442 136871919 6664568 ...
     $ V8: int  46526304 12061925 34417515 88974238 8291203 150294844 29190208 76448092 136875735 6670599 ...
>
```

Doing this manually is not an options, since I have a large number of input files that I would like so prune in the same manner.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using subset wrongly. The syntax of subset is

> ```
>     pruned1 <- subset(x, !( V5 == 1 & V7 > 113818477 & V8 < 114658477) )
> ```

("!" is the negation operator)

and not

> ```
>     pruned1 <- subset(x[-which(x$V5 == 1 & x$V7 > 113818477 & x$V8 < 114658477)
> ```

Hope that helps

PS You might want to look into whether using '&' or '&&' fits your situation best, I can't remember if that will cause a problem.

Comment: In this case, I don't think that using `&&` makes sense, see `?"&"` and [R: Logical operators: Beware of the difference between “&&” and “&”](http://promberger.info/linux/2008/09/12/r-logical-operators-beware-of-the-difference-between-and/) .

Comment: I think you meant `pruned1 <- subset(x, !(V5 == 1 & V7 > 113818477 & V8 < 114658477))` right? `pruned1` should exclude observations for which `V5==1 & ...`

Comment: Yes I wanted to exclude the observations that fulfilled the conditions. So this was exactly what I meant, thank you. The function works beautifully now.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `which`, then `subset` is unnecessary. If we have a logical condition these are equivalent in R:

```
data[cond,]
data[which(cond),]
subset(data,cond)
```

The benefit of the subset is that you do not need to use `$` to get to the variables you are subsetting on.

Furthermore if you do successive subsetings it makes more sense to concatenate all the conditions and then do subseting. So if you have the condition 1 and condition 2, which themselves may be complicated conditions then instead of

```
pruned1 <- data[cond1, ]
pruned2 <- pruned1[cond2, ]
```

Do

```
cond <- cond1 & cond2
pruned2 <- data[cond,]
```

The main benefit of the second approach that it is faster and cleaner, since you will not be creating new objects.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion about `which` and `subset`. I was doing it more complicated than it was. The tip about my successive subsetting is also speeding up my analyses, which is great.

Comment: @Caroline, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is

```
y <- 
    x[
        !(x$V5 == 1 & x$V7 > 113818477 & x$V8 < 114658477) &
        !(x$V5 == 1 & x$V7 > 192461456 & x$V8 < 192549912),
    ]
```

Also, V5 is a character variable, so `x$V5 == “1”` might be preferable -- e.g., if you have any codes that are actually formatted as " 1", you will need to take care to specify `x$V5 == “ 1”`. @ulvund `&` is necessary for this application because it returns element-wise logical AND, whereas `&&` “evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined” (?Logic).

Comment: I haven't even noticed that V5 was a character variable, thank you for pointing it out. Somehow it still worked, but it's good to know in downstream analyses. I am still confused about `&&`, but I am saving that for later.

Comment: @Caroline You can check everything easily in R: `"1"==1` returns true (T) but `" 1"==1` returns false (F). `c(T,F,T) & c(F,F,T)` returns `F,F,T` as expected but `c(T,F,T) && c(F,F,T)` returns `F` because it only compares the first element in each vector.